# Board to board connector on old home theater amplifier

Tags: amplifier, connector, board

I am taking apart an old amplifier and it has a connector that directly connects two PCB boards. I am unable to detach it by pulling it up.  Applying pressure to the two small indentations does not seem to have any effect. Anyone recognize it?

[image: stuck connector]

This is what the boards look like, there's also a black connector on the left and that one I can easily pull up:

[image]

Here's a close-up of the black connector as requested:

[image]

Comment: Reminiscent of ERNI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this type of connector pulls directly upwards without moving any latches. It required quite a lot of force and some wiggling

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like the two areas I've circled may be retainers or latches. Try spreading these apart as you pull on the vertical board.

[image: marked-up image]

Comment: I tried and it doesn't look like these move at all

Comment: OK, maybe they're just additional guides. What about the big rectangular hole in the center -- any chance that that's a latch?

Comment: It does not seem to give way. I tried applying pressure there while pulling up but no luck

Comment: Try prying the outer shell outward in the center above that hole by wedging something in the gap at the top. I'm guessing that this is a "mate-once" connector whose latching mechanism is intended to be permanent. So you are going to have to be creative about getting it apart. Otherwise, consider desoldering P611a from the lower board. It's only 12 pins on a single-sided board, so if done with care, it shouldn't cause any damage.

Comment: Or if you don't mind being a little destructive, consider extending that hole all the way to the top by cutting away the bar of plastic using nippers.

Answer (score 2):

I see a seam along the top of the white connector, a rectangular friction snap in the middle of the wide wall, and small latches on either end. That would indicate that you should move the two end-latches outward, then separate the boards by pulling the vertical board straight up.